# BalenaOS use Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 IO board's Real-Time Clock inside container

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, hardware, real-time-clock, balena

I'm trying to use the CM4 IO board's Real-Time Clock (RTC) to persist datetime changes from within a docker container, so whenever the device reboots, it remembers the newly set datetime. (By default it syncs via [chrony](https://www.balena.io/docs/reference/OS/time/#chrony).) I can update the system's datetime using the `date --set="<datetime string>"`, but upon reboot it re-syncs and overrides the previously set datetime.

To enable the OI board's RTC, you need to set `BALENA_HOST_CONFIG_dtparam="i2c_vc=on"` according to the IO board's datasheet:

I've done that (added fleet-wide configuration), after that I've also added `i2c-tools` to the container I want to use it in, which allows the usage of the `i2cdetect` command.
It can detect the RTC (with battery inserted off course) using the following command: `i2cdetect -y 10` (RTC is on i2c-10) which shows the RTC device on address 0x51 as stated by the datasheet:

```
     0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f
00:                         -- -- -- -- 0c -- -- -- 
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 2f 
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
40: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
50: -- 51 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
```

Although to me this looks like it's on 1x51, so maybe there's an issue there?
However, the address does seem to be correct, since I get the following result when running `i2cget -y 10 0x51`: `0x00`. Whereas when I run `i2cget -y 10 1x51`, I get: `Error: Chip address is not a number!`.
Just to be complete, this is what I get when I run (other i2c addresses in use, don't know what for):

- `i2cget -y 10 0x0c`: `0x5f`
- `i2cget -y 10 0x2f`: `0x00`

This is what I get when running `i2cdetect -l`:

```
i2c-10  i2c         i2c-22-mux (chan_id 1)              I2C adapter
i2c-0   i2c         i2c-22-mux (chan_id 0)              I2C adapter
i2c-22  i2c         bcm2835 (i2c@7e205000)              I2C adapter
```

This is also reflected when running `ls -hal /dev/i2c*` (same result inside container and on host OS):

```
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89,  0 Apr  5 12:49 /dev/i2c-0
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 10 Apr  5 12:49 /dev/i2c-10
crw-rw---- 1 root i2c 89, 22 Apr  5 12:49 /dev/i2c-22
```

This is the output when I run `dmesg | grep -E '(i2c|rtc)' | head -50`  (same result inside container and on host OS):

```
[    6.492981] i2c i2c-22: Added multiplexed i2c bus 0
[    6.493115] i2c i2c-22: Added multiplexed i2c bus 10
[    9.378968] i2c /dev entries driver
```

So far so good, it seems.

According to [this](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=318295) post on Raspberry Pi's forum, you also need to:

1. `echo pcf85063 0x51 >/sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-10/new_device`
2. `modprobe rtc-pcf85063`

I've added both these things to my docker setup (and also tried a few variations listed in that same post), however I don't think I even need this, since I can detect it right away after setting the `_dtparam`. Having done this or not doesn't seem to make any difference.

Normally, when everything is working correctly, you should be able to set, update, ... the RTC using the `hwclock` commands, but whenever I run that, I get the following message:

```
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --verbose option to see the details of our search for an access method.
```

This is the output when I run `hwclock --verbose`:

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.36.1
System Time: 1649177573.560553
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

When I run `timedatectl` on the host OS I get:

```
               Local time: Tue 2022-04-05 17:04:37 UTC
           Universal time: Tue 2022-04-05 17:04:37 UTC
                 RTC time: n/a
                Time zone: n/a (UTC, +0000)
System clock synchronized: yes
              NTP service: n/a
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

This seems to indicate the RTC is not working.

When running this command inside the container itself, I get:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here? Is this a permission/usergroup issue (since I'm trying to do this from inside a container)? Is it some wrong configuration? Am I missing some extra setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd also posted the same question on the [balena forum](https://forums.balena.io/t/balenaos-use-raspberry-pi-compute-module-4-io-boards-real-time-clock-inside-container/355610/9) and what I had to do was simply set `BALENA_HOST_CONFIG_dtoverlay` to `"i2c-rtc,pcf85063a,i2c_csi_dsi,addr=0x51"`.

Extra info: in the [CM4 IO board datasheet](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/cm4io/cm4io-datasheet.pdf) (Section 2.13) it indicates you only need to set `BALENA_HOST_CONFIG_dtparam` to `"i2c_vc=on"`, but this is not needed when setting the `dtoverlay` from above. I've tested with and without this and have found no difference.